# representing arithmetic expressions as trees

Tags: scala, tree, functional-programming

In order to prepare my self for the exam I am doing some scala assignment. 
The task is to implement a function evaluate in a companion object to Exp that evaluates the expression represented by its argument Exp. The function must obey the following signature:

```
Exp.evaluate(Exp):Int
```

When you are finished, the following code will print 1:

```
val e = Sub(Plus(Num(5),
 Mul(Num(9),
 Num(3))),
 Num(5))
println(Exp.evaluate(e))
```

and this is the code:I am stuck at this part as I am confused how to write the evaluate function. New working version:

```
sealed abstract case class Exp
case class Num(n : Int) extends Exp
case class Plus(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) extends Exp
case class  Mul(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) extends Exp
case class  Sub(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) extends Exp

object Exp {
  def evaluate(e : Exp) : Int = {
    e match {
      case Num(n) => n
      case Plus(n1, n2) => add(n1, n2)
      case Mul(n1, n2) => times(n1, n2)
      case Sub(n1, n2) => minus(n1, n2)
      //case _ => error("nothing")
    }
  }

  def add(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) : Int = (n1,n2) match {
    case (Num(x), Num(y)) => x+y
  }

  def times(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) : Int = (n1,n2) match {
    case (Num(x), Num(y)) => x*y
  }

  def minus(n1 : Exp, n2 : Exp) : Int = (n1,n2) match {
    case (Num(x), Num(y)) => x-y
  }
}
//
```

But now it doesnt pass my tests:

```
    def testEvalSkel {
    expect(11) {
      evaluate(Plus(Mul(Num(3),Num(4)),Sub(Num(3),Num(4))))
    }
  }
```

and I get this error:

```
Test testEvalSkel failed: (Mul(Num(3),Num(4)),Sub(Num(3),Num(4))) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

Comment: For starters, `Exp` should be `sealed` so you can safely pattern match over it.

Comment: Okay, so now you should pattern match over it. The method will look like: `def evaluate(e: Exp): Int = e match { case Num(n) => n; case Plus(n1, n2) => n1 + n2; case ... }`

Comment: @ChrisMartin do you know why I get type mismatch error??

Comment: Get rid of the extra `def`s in the companion object, and rename `PLus` to `Plus`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Dear Chris I tried to do what u said but I still get error: test.scala:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Num
 required: Int
      evaluate(Mul(Num(3),Num(4)))
 DO you know what am I doing wrong??? am I missing something?

Comment: You define `case class Plus(n1 : Int, n2 : Int) extends Exp`. This means you can create `Plus(2,3)` but not `Plus(Plus(1,1),3)` because `Plus(1,1)` is not an `Int`. Perhaps you should think how to define `Plus` a bit differently.

Comment: val e = Sub(Plus(Num(5), Mul(Num(9), Num(3))), Num(5))  The case classes expects Int and you are providing them with case class as explained by @n.m. try to modify your code a bit.

Comment: @n.m. if I change the type of Int to Exp do you think it woul make difference?

Comment: oki the new code runs fine, but when I test it I get error, and my tests wont pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Approach it works.

```
trait Exp

  case class Num(n: Int) extends Exp

  case class Plus(n1: Exp, n2: Exp) extends Exp

  case class Mul(n1: Exp, n2: Exp) extends Exp

  case class Sub(n1: Exp, n2: Exp) extends Exp

  object Exp {
    def evaluate(e: Exp): Int = {
      e match {
        case Num(n) => n
        case Plus(e1, e2) => add(e1,e2)
        case Mul(e1, e2) => times(e1, e2)
        case Sub(e1, e2) => minus(e1, e2)
      }
    }

    def add(n1: Exp, n2: Exp): Int = evaluate(n1) + evaluate(n2)

    def times(n1: Exp, n2: Exp): Int = evaluate(n1) *  evaluate(n2)

    def minus(n1: Exp, n2: Exp): Int = evaluate(n1) - evaluate(n2)
  }

  val e = Plus(Mul(Num(3),Num(4)),Sub(Num(3),Num(4)))
  println(Exp.evaluate(e)) // prints 11
```